# how to generate multiple copies of the same file using mule

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-el

Is there a way to get a file from an inbound File connector, and generate multiple copies (say, 5) of the same file within that same folder or a different location?  I have tried it with Scatter-Gather component, but it did not turn out the way I expected. Help, please?

If using Scatter-Gather is supposed to work, how do I write a MEL expression to alter the filename, keeping the original extension? My current mule flow is as follows.

```
<file:connector name="File_Send" readFromDirectory="C:\Users\AnypointStudio\workspace\MessageOut" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<file:connector name="File_Receive" autoDelete="true" streaming="true" validateConnections="true" doc:name="File"/>
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="readFile" class="java.lang.String">
        <spring:constructor-arg>
            <spring:bean class="org.springframework.util.FileCopyUtils" factory-method="copyToByteArray">
                <spring:constructor-arg type="java.io.InputStream" value="${C:\Users\AnypointStudio\workspace\MessageOut\24730717-99a3-4353-bfcc-d19d3ba7f50a.xml}"/>
            </spring:bean>
        </spring:constructor-arg>
    </spring:bean>
</spring:beans>
<flow name="loop_testFlow">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\AnypointStudio\workspace" connector-ref="File_Send" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <object-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="Object to Byte Array"/>
    <set-variable variableName="file" value="#[app.registry.readFile]" doc:name="Variable"/>
    <scatter-gather doc:name="Scatter-Gather">
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\AnypointStudio\workspace\MessageIn" connector-ref="File_Receive" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="C:\Users\AnypointStudio\workspace\MessageIn" connector-ref="File_Receive" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    </scatter-gather>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think with a list and foreach could be a solution:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:scripting="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting" xmlns:file="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:stdio="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio/current/mule-stdio.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/stdio/3.6/mule-stdio.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/3.6/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/scripting/current/mule-scripting.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/file/current/mule-file.xsd" version="EE-3.6.1">

    <stdio:connector name="stdioConnector"
        messageDelayTime="1234" outputMessage="abc" promptMessage="Enter number of files:"
        doc:name="STDIO" />

    <flow name="flow">
        <stdio:inbound-endpoint system="IN" connector-ref="stdioConnector" doc:name="STDIO"/>
        <logger message="generating #[payload] files" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
            <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><![CDATA[

                list = new ArrayList();

                int fin = payload.toInteger()

                (1..fin).each {
                    list.add("file_00${it}.txt")
                }

                return list

            ]]></scripting:script>
        </scripting:component>
        <foreach collection="#[payload]" doc:name="For Each">
            <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
            <object-to-string-transformer doc:name="Object to String"/>
            <file:outbound-endpoint path="D:\opt" outputPattern="#[payload]" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File outbound"/>
        </foreach>

    </flow>
</mule>
```

This example ask you the number of files:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Here the project:

https://github.com/jrichardsz/mule-esb-usefull-templates/tree/master/several-output-file

Luck!

Answer (score 1):

Use below MEL to get the file name then you can append the extra string (in case you know the extension with the files your working then you can add it in the end)

```
#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename']]+'Testing'.txt
```

in case you don't know then you need get extension first

```
<set-variable value="#[org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils.getExtension(originalFilename)]" variableName="extension" doc:name="Set extension" />
```

then write like below in file outbound for fileName/pattern field

```
#[message.inboundProperties['originalFilename'].substring(0,message.inboundProperties['originalFilename'].lastIndexOf('.'))]_Testing.#[flowVars.extension]
```

Comment: Tried that, but still not able to set a specific number of copies. +1 for the MEL expressions though. Came in handy for a few other operations. Kudos!